# Flexslider empty slide

Tags: plugins, php, customization, slideshow

I'm using flexslider with wp and my slider have 2 slides in view as one,
 the problem is when i have Steady number of slides i got one extra blank slide,also at that case my newest two slides goes to last position, and when i have odd then everything is fine.

```
<?php
$post_counter = wp_count_posts('news');
$numOfPosts = (int)$post_counter->publish;
$i = 1;?>  <div class="flexslider flexslider-wrapper " id="slide1">
<div class="row nav-contain">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="flex-nav-container">
            <div class="flex-nav">

            </div>
        </div><!-- /.flex-nav-container -->


        </div>
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
        <?php
        query_posts(array(
        'showposts' => -1,
        'post_type' =>'news',
        'orderby' => 'publish_date',
        'order'   => 'DESC'
        ));

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="item-title">
                    <a class="item-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></a>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo mb_strimwidth( get_the_title(), 0, 40, '...' );?></a></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="exceprt">
                    <?php echo  the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        $i++;

        if($i % 2 == 1 && $numOfPosts > 2){
            echo '</li><li>';
        }
        endwhile;endif;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

EDIT:
Partial solution to this is animationLoop: false,
in this way i get all well sorted, but problem is that i need to use animationloop, last slide still empty also i provide my js:

```
 $('#slide-1').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlsContainer: '#slide-1 .flex-nav',
    manualControls: '#slide-1 .flex-control-nav li',
    controlNav: false,
    slideshow: false,


});
```

REEDIT:
When i remove animation:"slide", posts are in right orded (newest-oldest), but last slide stil empty.

Comment: `query_posts` should never be used and causes all manner of problems. Use `WP_Query` instead

Comment: Thx for this @TomJNowell , will fix and avoid in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with putting integer to -1,don't know really why this helped but if someone get same problem then maybe this will help to him.

```
<?php $i = -1;
 if (have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 if ($i%2 == 1) echo '</li><li>'; 
 ?>
```

Comment: it's because your loop adds an opening `<li>` tag at the end, and the math is off, so you'd end up with 1 extra `li` tag, depending on wether an even or an odd number of posts were fetched